# BERT-CNN layer: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, bert-language-model

I'm trying to fine-tune a BERT model with a CNN layer on top, but get the error:

conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple!, !tuple!, !tuple!, int)

Code:

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertTokenizer, AdamW
import torch.nn as nn
import pytorch_lightning as pl

class CommentModule(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, n_classes=13):
      super().__init__()
      self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
      self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=13, out_channels=13, kernel_size=(3, 768), padding=True)
      self.relu = nn.ReLU()
      self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=1)
      self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
      self.fc = nn.Linear(442, 3)
      self.flat = nn.Flatten()
      self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
      # outputs[2]  = [13, 32, 128, 768] 
      outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask, output_hidden_states=True)

      # x now of shape = [32, 13, 128, 768] 
      # ([13 layers?, 32=batch size, 128=max_seq_length, 729=BERT hidden size)
      x = torch.transpose(torch.cat(tuple([t.unsqueeze(0) for t in outputs[2]]), 0), 0, 1)

      x = self.dropout(x)

      ########### ERROR OCCURS AT self.conv(x)
      x = self.conv(x)
      ######################

      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.dropout(x)
      x = self.pool(x)
      x = self.fc(self.dropout(self.flat(self.dropout(x))))
      return self.softmax(x)

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
    labels = batch['labels']
    loss, outputs = self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    return {'loss': loss, 'predictions': outputs, 'labels': labels}
```

Notice that my received arguments are
"(Tensor, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int)", while the expected arguments are
"(Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)". These *almost* match? 1 Tensor 2 "Parameters" vs. 3 Tensors, 3 tuples vs. 3 "tuple of ints", int vs. int?

I have no clue, help greatly appreciated.

Comment: add the imports. fix the `super()` presumably by adding the class. such that there is sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Fixed as far as I can see. If there's anything I missed, do let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) of Conv1d, the input shape must be `(N, C, L)`, or `(C, L)`, where:

- `N` is the batch size
- `C` is the number of channels
- `L` is the sequence length

I notice that you have the line `# x now of shape = [32, 13, 128, 768]`, which clearly means that it mismatches the shape of Conv1d.

In your case, you can either aggregate the output tensor to match the requirements, or just not returning the hidden state.

Comment: Oh no! I'm actually working with Conv2d, but I made edits messing around with Conv1d and forgot to change it back for this post. Apologies, that's my bad.
Though even not returning the hidden state (so having x = [32, 13, 128], I get the exact same error.

Comment: Conv2d requires the input to have 4 dimensions. In that case, you should also return the hidden states

Comment: Right, that was already the case. The issue seems to lie with the argument types: conv1d/conv2d is receiving Tensor, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int, but expects Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, tuple, tuple, tuple, int

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, consider marking it "accepted" :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, however it did not solve anything (as my previous comments would suggest)